# how to extract feed deltas from facebook realtime update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

What I want is to be able to act on specific updates to a user's feed:  When someone else comments on a user's post/photo/link, someone else comments on a comment, someone else likes comment or post by my user, tags a user in a photo, etc.  In these cases we notify the user of the exact change that occurred so we need to know exactly what changed/happened and act on it.

I have realtime working, challenge handled, checking sha1 signature, etc.   The update itself just tells me essentially: "User A's feed has changed".  What I wish I got was "These are the changes since last time".

I can think of a couple ways to go about this but they all seem pretty heavy handed:

- Keep a copy of each user's feed with each update, manually diff by iterating over each key, decide if the changes I detect are changes I need to act on.   I'm still not sure this would even work because I only see the last few posts.  Do comments/likes of a post reorder that post to the front?
- Track the timestamp of the most recent change in every update, then filter by that in subsequent updates.   This still means I have to iterate over every post/comment/like in the entire feed.
- I read somewhere that post/comment ids increase monotonically.  Is that true per user's feed?  For comments is that just local to the post?  Do posts/comments/likes share an id pool so I could rely on this globally?   Again not sure about a lot of details here but in that case I could track the highest id seen in one update, and filter on that in subsequent updates.

Anyway, all these seem very brute force.  Specific advice or methods are much appreciated.   Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any way I can get "real time updates" when there is a change in newsfeed of the user ?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the 'after' cursor from the hash that [Graph pagination](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) returns, per post type you handle and comments, etc. Then do an [expanded field select](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) for the feed, grabbing all the posts, comments, likes, etc.

Compare your after cursors with those in the hash from the expanded field select and throw away what hasn't changed.

Do a [batch API request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) for what remains in the hash and process that.